# Google Chrome displaying special characters for File ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, encoding, character-encoding

I need to return HTML (complete document in itself, not chunk) obtained from an external source. After getting the HTML string I convert it to byte array using a helper method, and return in the Action using `return File()`

**This works without issues on IE and FF**. But in Chrome (37.0.2062.124 m), the HTML document is displayed as-is, along with special characters as shown in the image.

**How do I get rid of the special characters in Chrome as shown in the image?**

Right click view source in Chrome does not have any special characters.

Controller:

```
return File(SingletonCommon.Instance.GetBytes(htmlResponse), "text/html");
```

Helper method:

```
public byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Undesired Result (with special characters):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg0WX.png
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg0WX.png]

I tried adding `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to `<head>` but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use the File result?:

```
return Content(htmlResponse, "text/html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```